# Como encontrar outro nome igual ao selecionado e destacar

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Calendario com os nomes]

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma forma de encontrar nomes iguais e destacar Aonde estão com a classe efeitos!, alguem sabe como?

Obrigado!

`

```js
<script>
jQuery('#confirmados li').on('mouseover', function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.addClass('efeitos');
    console.log($this);

});
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.efeitos {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.efeitos:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
</style>
```

```html
<table style="font-size:0.75em;" class="m-0 p-0 calendar table table-condensed table-bordered"><tbody><tr id="cabecalhocalendario"><th class="header text-center ">DOM</th><th class="header text-center ">SEG</th><th class="header text-center ">TER</th><th class="header text-center ">QUA</th><th class="header text-center ">QUI</th><th class="header text-center ">SEX</th><th class="header text-center ">SAB</th></tr><tr><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-01"><b>1</b><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="BRUNO ALAN DE ALMEIDA HORACIO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="134" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="BRUNO ALAN" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>BRUNO ALAN</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="CLAUDECI ALEXANDRE DA SILVA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="128" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="CLAUDECI ALEXANDRE" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>CLAUDECI ALEXANDRE</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="EWERTON GAMA VENCESLAU" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="193" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="EWERTON GAMA" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#DAA520    " class="EWERTON GAMA VENCESLAU list-group-item  m-0 p-0 efeitos"><span>EWERTON GAMA</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="GILMAR ANTONIO DA MOTA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="206" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="GILMAR" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>GILMAR</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="JOAO PAULO DA SILVA FERRAZ" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="224" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="JOAO PAULO FERRAZ" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>JOAO PAULO FERRAZ</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="LEANDRO RIBEIRO CAMARGO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="89" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="LEANDRO RIBEIRO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#7FFFD4" class="LEANDRO RIBEIRO CAMARGO list-group-item  m-0 p-0 efeitos"><span>LEANDRO RIBEIRO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="LEONICE DO NASCIMENTO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="114" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="LEONICE" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>LEONICE</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="MARCIO RIBEIRO DE OLIVEIRA ORSI" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="97" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="MARCIO RIBEIRO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>MARCIO RIBEIRO</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="SERGIO RODRIGUES LAUBE" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="300" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="SERGIO LAUBE" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>SERGIO LAUBE</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="TIAGO BELO ZERIAL" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="313" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="TIAGO BELO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#FFFFE0" class="TIAGO BELO ZERIAL list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>TIAGO BELO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="VINICIUS FERREIRA ARAUJO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="110" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="VINICIUS FERREIRA" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#F0E68C" class="VINICIUS FERREIRA ARAUJO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>VINICIUS FERREIRA</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="VINICIUS SILVA SAVALHO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="326" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="VINICIUS SAVALHO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>VINICIUS SAVALHO</span></li></ul><table class="col alert-warning"><tbody><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr></tbody></table></td><td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-02"><b>2</b><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO RODRIGUES CARDOZO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="146" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="" data-nome="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>ALEXANDRE APARECIDO</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="155" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="" data-nome="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>ANDRE SCHIAVINATO</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="CARLOS ALBERTO PEREIRA DIAS FILHO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="176" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="CARLOS ALBERTO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#98FB98" class="CARLOS ALBERTO PEREIRA DIAS FILHO list-group-item  m-0 p-0 efeitos"><span>CARLOS ALBERTO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="DANILO DOS SANTOS ARAUJO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="102" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="" data-nome="DANILO ARAUJO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>DANILO ARAUJO</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="ELI CARLOS PEREIRA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="179" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="ELI CARLOS" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#2EFE2E" class="ELI CARLOS PEREIRA list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>ELI CARLOS</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="GILSON BENEDITO DE CASTRO LOPES " class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="216" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="" data-nome="GILSON BENEDITO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>GILSON BENEDITO</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="MARCIO JORGE MELANDA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="248" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="" data-nome="MARCIO MELANDA" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>MARCIO MELANDA</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="PAULO FERREIRA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="270" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="" data-nome="PAULO FERREIRA" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>PAULO FERREIRA</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="RONALDO FIRMINO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="286" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="07:30" data-nome="RONALDO FIRMINO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#DEB887" class="RONALDO FIRMINO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>RONALDO FIRMINO</span><b class=""> 07:30</b></li></ul><table class="col alert-warning"><tbody><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr></tbody></table></td><td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-03"><b>3</b><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="ANTONIO CARLOS VIEIRA SOARES" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="165" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="ANTONIO VIEIRA" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>ANTONIO VIEIRA</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="BRUNO ALAN DE ALMEIDA HORACIO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="135" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="BRUNO ALAN" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>BRUNO ALAN</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="CLAUDINEI FERNANDO FRANCA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="121" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="CLAUDINEI FERNANDO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>CLAUDINEI FERNANDO</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="GILMAR ANTONIO DA MOTA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="207" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="GILMAR" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#E0E0F8" class="GILMAR ANTONIO DA MOTA list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>GILMAR</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="JOAO PAULO DA SILVA FERRAZ" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="225" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="JOAO PAULO FERRAZ" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#1E90FF" class="JOAO PAULO DA SILVA FERRAZ list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>JOAO PAULO FERRAZ</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="LEONICE DO NASCIMENTO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="115" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="LEONICE" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>LEONICE</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="MARCIO RIBEIRO DE OLIVEIRA ORSI" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="98" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="MARCIO RIBEIRO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>MARCIO RIBEIRO</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="SERGIO RODRIGUES LAUBE" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="301" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="SERGIO LAUBE" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>SERGIO LAUBE</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="TIAGO BELO ZERIAL" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="314" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="TIAGO BELO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#FFFFE0" class="TIAGO BELO ZERIAL list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>TIAGO BELO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="VINICIUS FERREIRA ARAUJO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="111" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="VINICIUS FERREIRA" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>VINICIUS FERREIRA</span></li></ul><table class="col alert-warning"><tbody><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr></tbody></table></td><td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-04"><b>4</b><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO RODRIGUES CARDOZO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="147" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="" data-nome="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>ALEXANDRE APARECIDO</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="156" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#EEE8AA" class="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>ANDRE SCHIAVINATO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="DANILO DOS SANTOS ARAUJO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="103" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="DANILO ARAUJO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#BDBDBD" class="DANILO DOS SANTOS ARAUJO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>DANILO ARAUJO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="GILSON BENEDITO DE CASTRO LOPES " class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="217" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="07:30" data-nome="GILSON BENEDITO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#A9F5A9" class="GILSON BENEDITO DE CASTRO LOPES  list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>GILSON BENEDITO</span><b class=""> 07:30</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="MARCIO JORGE MELANDA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="249" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="" data-nome="MARCIO MELANDA" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>MARCIO MELANDA</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="PAULO FERREIRA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="271" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="" data-nome="PAULO FERREIRA" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>PAULO FERREIRA</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="RONALDO FIRMINO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="287" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="" data-nome="RONALDO FIRMINO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>RONALDO FIRMINO</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="TONY JUPSSON SANTOS" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="315" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="" data-nome="TONY JUPSSON" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>TONY JUPSSON</span></li></ul><table class="col alert-warning"><tbody><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr></tbody></table></td><td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-05"><b>5</b><ul id="confirmados" title="BRUNO ALAN DE ALMEIDA HORACIO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="136" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="07:30" data-nome="BRUNO ALAN" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#642EFE" class="BRUNO ALAN DE ALMEIDA HORACIO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>BRUNO ALAN</span><b class=""> 07:30</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="CLAUDECI ALEXANDRE DA SILVA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="129" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="" data-nome="CLAUDECI ALEXANDRE" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>CLAUDECI ALEXANDRE</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="CLAUDINEI FERNANDO FRANCA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="122" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="CLAUDINEI FERNANDO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#0B6138" class="CLAUDINEI FERNANDO FRANCA list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>CLAUDINEI FERNANDO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="GILMAR ANTONIO DA MOTA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="208" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="" data-nome="GILMAR" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>GILMAR</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="JOAO PAULO DA SILVA FERRAZ" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="226" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="" data-nome="JOAO PAULO FERRAZ" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>JOAO PAULO FERRAZ</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="LEONICE DO NASCIMENTO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="116" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="" data-nome="LEONICE" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>LEONICE</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="SERGIO RODRIGUES LAUBE" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="302" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="" data-nome="SERGIO LAUBE" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>SERGIO LAUBE</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="VINICIUS FERREIRA ARAUJO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="112" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="" data-nome="VINICIUS FERREIRA" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>VINICIUS FERREIRA</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="VINICIUS SILVA SAVALHO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="327" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="VINICIUS SAVALHO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#87CEEB" class="VINICIUS SILVA SAVALHO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>VINICIUS SAVALHO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><table class="col alert-warning"><tbody><tr class=""></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr></tbody></table></td><td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-06"><b>6</b><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO RODRIGUES CARDOZO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="148" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="" data-nome="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>ALEXANDRE APARECIDO</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="BENEVALDO DE JESUS LEAL FILHO " class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="171" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="" data-nome="BENEVALDO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>BENEVALDO</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="CRISTIANE DE CARVALHO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="91" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="08:00" data-nome="CRISTIANE" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#DF01A5" class="CRISTIANE DE CARVALHO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>CRISTIANE</span><b class=""> 08:00</b></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="GUSTAVO DA SILVA LUPERINI" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="333" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="08:00" data-nome="GUSTAVO LUPERINI" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#E6E6E6" class="GUSTAVO DA SILVA LUPERINI list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>GUSTAVO LUPERINI</span><b class=""> 08:00</b></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="JORGE CAMILO DE SOUSA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="234" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="07:30" data-nome="JORGE CAMILO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#FFA500" class="JORGE CAMILO DE SOUSA list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>JORGE CAMILO</span><b class=""> 07:30</b></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="JOSE AUGUSTO FERREIRA GOMES" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="236" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="07:30" data-nome="JOSE AUGUSTO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#87CEFA" class="JOSE AUGUSTO FERREIRA GOMES list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>JOSE AUGUSTO</span><b class=""> 07:30</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="PAULO FERREIRA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="272" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="" data-nome="PAULO FERREIRA" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>PAULO FERREIRA</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="RONALDO FIRMINO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="288" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="" data-nome="RONALDO FIRMINO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>RONALDO FIRMINO</span></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="SILVIO RODRIGUES FIGUEIREDO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="84" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="" data-nome="SILVIO RODRIGUES" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>SILVIO RODRIGUES</span></li></ul><table class="col alert-warning"><tbody><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-07"><b>7</b><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="CRISTIANE DE CARVALHO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="92" data-escolhida="2021-02-07" data-horario="" data-nome="CRISTIANE" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>CRISTIANE</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="ELIANE GANDOLFO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="335" data-escolhida="2021-02-07" data-horario="08:00" data-nome="ELIANE GANDOLFO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#F5A9E1" class="ELIANE GANDOLFO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>ELIANE GANDOLFO</span><b class=""> 08:00</b></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="EVERTON HENRIQUE DE LIMA" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="189" data-escolhida="2021-02-07" data-horario="08:00" data-nome="EVERTON HENRIQUE" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#585858" class="EVERTON HENRIQUE DE LIMA list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>EVERTON HENRIQUE</span><b class=""> 08:00</b></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="LEONICE DO NASCIMENTO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="117" data-escolhida="2021-02-07" data-horario="08:00" data-nome="LEONICE" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#DAA520" class="LEONICE DO NASCIMENTO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>LEONICE</span><b class=""> 08:00</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="SERGIO RODRIGUES LAUBE" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="303" data-escolhida="2021-02-07" data-horario="" data-nome="SERGIO LAUBE" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>SERGIO LAUBE</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="VINICIUS FERREIRA ARAUJO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="113" data-escolhida="2021-02-07" data-horario="08:00" data-nome="VINICIUS FERREIRA" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#F0E68C" class="VINICIUS FERREIRA ARAUJO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>VINICIUS FERREIRA</span><b class=""> 08:00</b></li></ul><table class="col alert-warning"><tbody><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class=""></tr><tr class="alert-warning"></tr><tr class=""></tr></tbody></table></td><td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-08"><b>8</b><ul id="confirmados" title="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO RODRIGUES CARDOZO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="149" data-escolhida="2021-02-08" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#04B4AE" class="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO RODRIGUES CARDOZO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>ALEXANDRE APARECIDO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="157" data-escolhida="2021-02-08" data-horario="" data-nome="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>ANDRE SCHIAVINATO</span></li></ul><ul id="confirmados" title="DANILO DOS SANTOS ARAUJO" class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="104" data-escolhida="2021-02-08" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="DANILO ARAUJO" data-status="CONFIRMADO"><li style="background-color:#BDBDBD" class="DANILO DOS SANTOS ARAUJO list-group-item  m-0 p-0 efeitos"><span>DANILO ARAUJO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li></ul><ul draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" title="GILSON BENEDITO DE CASTRO LOPES " class="list-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="218" data-escolhida="2021-02-08" data-horario="" data-nome="GILSON BENEDITO" data-status="PENDENTE"><li class="list-group-item p-0 m-0"><span>GILSON BENEDITO</span></li></ul><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está passando para a function o elemento `LI` que tem o `mouseover`, para pegar o `span` pode usar um `find("span")` e pagar o texto do elemento.

Em seguida, encontrar os elementos span com o mesmo conteúdo. Para isso pode fazer `$("span:contains('NOME PROCURADO')");`, onde o nome deve ser o quem encontrou anteriormente.

Veja um exemplo (note que usei o evento `mouseleave` para remover a classe):

```js
jQuery('#confirmados li').on('mouseover', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this.find("span").text();

      var $mesmoTexto = $("span:contains('"+ name +"')");
  
    $mesmoTexto.addClass('efeitos');
});

jQuery('#confirmados li').on('mouseleave', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this.find("span").text();
      var $mesmoTexto = $("span:contains('"+ name +"')");
   
    $mesmoTexto.removeClass('efeitos');
});
```

```css
.efeitos {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="font-size:0.75em;" class="m-0 p-0 calendar table table-condensed table-bordered">
   <tbody>
      <tr id="cabecalhocalendario">
         <th class="header text-center ">DOM</th>
         <th class="header text-center ">SEG</th>
         <th class="header text-center ">TER</th>
         <th class="header text-center ">QUA</th>
         <th class="header text-center ">QUI</th>
         <th class="header text-center ">SEX</th>
         <th class="header text-center ">SAB</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-01">
            <b>1</b>
            <ul title="BRUNO ALAN DE ALMEIDA HORACIO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="134" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="BRUNO ALAN" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>BRUNO ALAN</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="CLAUDECI ALEXANDRE DA SILVA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="128" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="CLAUDECI ALEXANDRE" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>CLAUDECI ALEXANDRE</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="EWERTON GAMA VENCESLAU" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="193" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="EWERTON GAMA" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#DAA520  " class="EWERTON GAMA VENCESLAU list-group-item  m-0 p-0 efeitos"><span>EWERTON GAMA</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="GILMAR ANTONIO DA MOTA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="206" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="GILMAR" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>GILMAR</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="JOAO PAULO DA SILVA FERRAZ" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="224" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="JOAO PAULO FERRAZ" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>JOAO PAULO FERRAZ</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="LEANDRO RIBEIRO CAMARGO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="89" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="LEANDRO RIBEIRO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#7FFFD4" class="LEANDRO RIBEIRO CAMARGO list-group-item  m-0 p-0 efeitos"><span>LEANDRO RIBEIRO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="LEONICE DO NASCIMENTO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="114" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="LEONICE" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>LEONICE</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="MARCIO RIBEIRO DE OLIVEIRA ORSI" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="97" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="MARCIO RIBEIRO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>MARCIO RIBEIRO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="SERGIO RODRIGUES LAUBE" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="300" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="SERGIO LAUBE" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>SERGIO LAUBE</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="TIAGO BELO ZERIAL" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="313" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="TIAGO BELO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#FFFFE0" class="TIAGO BELO ZERIAL list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>TIAGO BELO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="VINICIUS FERREIRA ARAUJO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="110" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="VINICIUS FERREIRA" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#F0E68C" class="VINICIUS FERREIRA ARAUJO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>VINICIUS FERREIRA</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="VINICIUS SILVA SAVALHO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="326" data-escolhida="2021-02-01" data-horario="" data-nome="VINICIUS SAVALHO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>VINICIUS SAVALHO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <table class="col alert-warning">
               <tbody>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
         <td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-02">
            <b>2</b>
            <ul title="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO RODRIGUES CARDOZO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="146" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="" data-nome="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>ALEXANDRE APARECIDO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="155" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="" data-nome="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>ANDRE SCHIAVINATO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="CARLOS ALBERTO PEREIRA DIAS FILHO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="176" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="CARLOS ALBERTO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#98FB98" class="CARLOS ALBERTO PEREIRA DIAS FILHO list-group-item  m-0 p-0 efeitos"><span>CARLOS ALBERTO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="DANILO DOS SANTOS ARAUJO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="102" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="" data-nome="DANILO ARAUJO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>DANILO ARAUJO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="ELI CARLOS PEREIRA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="179" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="ELI CARLOS" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#2EFE2E" class="ELI CARLOS PEREIRA list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>ELI CARLOS</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="GILSON BENEDITO DE CASTRO LOPES " data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="216" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="" data-nome="GILSON BENEDITO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>GILSON BENEDITO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="MARCIO JORGE MELANDA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="248" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="" data-nome="MARCIO MELANDA" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>MARCIO MELANDA</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="PAULO FERREIRA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="270" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="" data-nome="PAULO FERREIRA" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>PAULO FERREIRA</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="RONALDO FIRMINO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="286" data-escolhida="2021-02-02" data-horario="07:30" data-nome="RONALDO FIRMINO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#DEB887" class="RONALDO FIRMINO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>RONALDO FIRMINO</span><b class=""> 07:30</b></li>
            </ul>
            <table class="col alert-warning">
               <tbody>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
         <td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-03">
            <b>3</b>
            <ul title="ANTONIO CARLOS VIEIRA SOARES" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="165" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="ANTONIO VIEIRA" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>ANTONIO VIEIRA</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="BRUNO ALAN DE ALMEIDA HORACIO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="135" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="BRUNO ALAN" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>BRUNO ALAN</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="CLAUDINEI FERNANDO FRANCA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="121" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="CLAUDINEI FERNANDO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>CLAUDINEI FERNANDO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="GILMAR ANTONIO DA MOTA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="207" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="GILMAR" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#E0E0F8" class="GILMAR ANTONIO DA MOTA list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>GILMAR</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="JOAO PAULO DA SILVA FERRAZ" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="225" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="JOAO PAULO FERRAZ" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#1E90FF" class="JOAO PAULO DA SILVA FERRAZ list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>JOAO PAULO FERRAZ</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="LEONICE DO NASCIMENTO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="115" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="LEONICE" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>LEONICE</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="MARCIO RIBEIRO DE OLIVEIRA ORSI" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="98" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="MARCIO RIBEIRO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>MARCIO RIBEIRO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="SERGIO RODRIGUES LAUBE" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="301" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="SERGIO LAUBE" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>SERGIO LAUBE</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="TIAGO BELO ZERIAL" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="314" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="TIAGO BELO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#FFFFE0" class="TIAGO BELO ZERIAL list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>TIAGO BELO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="VINICIUS FERREIRA ARAUJO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="111" data-escolhida="2021-02-03" data-horario="" data-nome="VINICIUS FERREIRA" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>VINICIUS FERREIRA</span></li>
            </ul>
            <table class="col alert-warning">
               <tbody>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
         <td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-04">
            <b>4</b>
            <ul title="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO RODRIGUES CARDOZO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="147" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="" data-nome="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>ALEXANDRE APARECIDO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="156" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#EEE8AA" class="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>ANDRE SCHIAVINATO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="DANILO DOS SANTOS ARAUJO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="103" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="DANILO ARAUJO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#BDBDBD" class="DANILO DOS SANTOS ARAUJO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>DANILO ARAUJO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="GILSON BENEDITO DE CASTRO LOPES " data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="217" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="07:30" data-nome="GILSON BENEDITO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#A9F5A9" class="GILSON BENEDITO DE CASTRO LOPES  list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>GILSON BENEDITO</span><b class=""> 07:30</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="MARCIO JORGE MELANDA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="249" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="" data-nome="MARCIO MELANDA" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>MARCIO MELANDA</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="PAULO FERREIRA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="271" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="" data-nome="PAULO FERREIRA" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>PAULO FERREIRA</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="RONALDO FIRMINO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="287" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="" data-nome="RONALDO FIRMINO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>RONALDO FIRMINO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="TONY JUPSSON SANTOS" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="315" data-escolhida="2021-02-04" data-horario="" data-nome="TONY JUPSSON" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>TONY JUPSSON</span></li>
            </ul>
            <table class="col alert-warning">
               <tbody>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
         <td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-05">
            <b>5</b>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="BRUNO ALAN DE ALMEIDA HORACIO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="136" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="07:30" data-nome="BRUNO ALAN" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#642EFE" class="BRUNO ALAN DE ALMEIDA HORACIO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>BRUNO ALAN</span><b class=""> 07:30</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="CLAUDECI ALEXANDRE DA SILVA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="129" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="" data-nome="CLAUDECI ALEXANDRE" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>CLAUDECI ALEXANDRE</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="CLAUDINEI FERNANDO FRANCA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="122" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="CLAUDINEI FERNANDO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#0B6138" class="CLAUDINEI FERNANDO FRANCA list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>CLAUDINEI FERNANDO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="GILMAR ANTONIO DA MOTA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="208" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="" data-nome="GILMAR" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>GILMAR</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="JOAO PAULO DA SILVA FERRAZ" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="226" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="" data-nome="JOAO PAULO FERRAZ" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>JOAO PAULO FERRAZ</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="LEONICE DO NASCIMENTO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="116" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="" data-nome="LEONICE" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>LEONICE</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="SERGIO RODRIGUES LAUBE" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="302" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="" data-nome="SERGIO LAUBE" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>SERGIO LAUBE</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="VINICIUS FERREIRA ARAUJO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="112" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="" data-nome="VINICIUS FERREIRA" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>VINICIUS FERREIRA</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="VINICIUS SILVA SAVALHO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="327" data-escolhida="2021-02-05" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="VINICIUS SAVALHO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#87CEEB" class="VINICIUS SILVA SAVALHO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>VINICIUS SAVALHO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <table class="col alert-warning">
               <tbody>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
         <td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-06">
            <b>6</b>
            <ul title="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO RODRIGUES CARDOZO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="148" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="" data-nome="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>ALEXANDRE APARECIDO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="BENEVALDO DE JESUS LEAL FILHO " data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="171" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="" data-nome="BENEVALDO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>BENEVALDO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="CRISTIANE DE CARVALHO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="91" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="08:00" data-nome="CRISTIANE" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#DF01A5" class="CRISTIANE DE CARVALHO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>CRISTIANE</span><b class=""> 08:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="GUSTAVO DA SILVA LUPERINI" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="333" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="08:00" data-nome="GUSTAVO LUPERINI" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#E6E6E6" class="GUSTAVO DA SILVA LUPERINI list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>GUSTAVO LUPERINI</span><b class=""> 08:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="JORGE CAMILO DE SOUSA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="234" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="07:30" data-nome="JORGE CAMILO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#FFA500" class="JORGE CAMILO DE SOUSA list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>JORGE CAMILO</span><b class=""> 07:30</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="JOSE AUGUSTO FERREIRA GOMES" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="236" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="07:30" data-nome="JOSE AUGUSTO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#87CEFA" class="JOSE AUGUSTO FERREIRA GOMES list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>JOSE AUGUSTO</span><b class=""> 07:30</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="PAULO FERREIRA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="272" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="" data-nome="PAULO FERREIRA" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>PAULO FERREIRA</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="RONALDO FIRMINO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="288" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="" data-nome="RONALDO FIRMINO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>RONALDO FIRMINO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="SILVIO RODRIGUES FIGUEIREDO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="84" data-escolhida="2021-02-06" data-horario="" data-nome="SILVIO RODRIGUES" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>SILVIO RODRIGUES</span></li>
            </ul>
            <table class="col alert-warning">
               <tbody>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-07">
            <b>7</b>
            <ul title="CRISTIANE DE CARVALHO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="92" data-escolhida="2021-02-07" data-horario="" data-nome="CRISTIANE" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>CRISTIANE</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="ELIANE GANDOLFO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="335" data-escolhida="2021-02-07" data-horario="08:00" data-nome="ELIANE GANDOLFO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#F5A9E1" class="ELIANE GANDOLFO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>ELIANE GANDOLFO</span><b class=""> 08:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="EVERTON HENRIQUE DE LIMA" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="189" data-escolhida="2021-02-07" data-horario="08:00" data-nome="EVERTON HENRIQUE" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#585858" class="EVERTON HENRIQUE DE LIMA list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>EVERTON HENRIQUE</span><b class=""> 08:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="LEONICE DO NASCIMENTO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="117" data-escolhida="2021-02-07" data-horario="08:00" data-nome="LEONICE" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#DAA520" class="LEONICE DO NASCIMENTO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>LEONICE</span><b class=""> 08:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="SERGIO RODRIGUES LAUBE" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="303" data-escolhida="2021-02-07" data-horario="" data-nome="SERGIO LAUBE" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>SERGIO LAUBE</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="VINICIUS FERREIRA ARAUJO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="113" data-escolhida="2021-02-07" data-horario="08:00" data-nome="VINICIUS FERREIRA" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#F0E68C" class="VINICIUS FERREIRA ARAUJO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>VINICIUS FERREIRA</span><b class=""> 08:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <table class="col alert-warning">
               <tbody>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
                  <tr class="alert-warning"></tr>
                  <tr class=""></tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
         <td class="day text-center" rel="2021-02-08">
            <b>8</b>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO RODRIGUES CARDOZO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="149" data-escolhida="2021-02-08" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#04B4AE" class="ALEXANDRE APARECIDO RODRIGUES CARDOZO list-group-item  m-0 p-0"><span>ALEXANDRE APARECIDO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="157" data-escolhida="2021-02-08" data-horario="" data-nome="ANDRE SCHIAVINATO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>ANDRE SCHIAVINATO</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="confirmados" title="DANILO DOS SANTOS ARAUJO" data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="104" data-escolhida="2021-02-08" data-horario="09:00" data-nome="DANILO ARAUJO" data-status="CONFIRMADO">
               <li style="background-color:#BDBDBD" class="DANILO DOS SANTOS ARAUJO list-group-item  m-0 p-0 efeitos"><span>DANILO ARAUJO</span><b class=""> 09:00</b></li>
            </ul>
            <ul title="GILSON BENEDITO DE CASTRO LOPES " data-target="#atualizarPedido" data-codigo="218" data-escolhida="2021-02-08" data-horario="" data-nome="GILSON BENEDITO" data-status="PENDENTE">
               <li><span>GILSON BENEDITO</span></li>
            </ul>
         <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Valeu obrigado pela ajuda!